# Access function in fragment in from main ViewPager fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to access function in second fragment from ViewPager fragment, but I've this error every time.

### java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.eltoh.date.onboarding.screens.ChatListFragment

I tried to execute this function many times, but the error still. Below, a code sample from both fragments.
If anyone can help. Thank you...

The required function in second fragment

```
fun clearAdapter() {
        chatListAdapter.clearList()
        chatListAdapter.getSelectedItem().clear()
    }
```

Function calling in ViewPager fragment

```
view?.backSelBtn?.setOnClickListener {
                val fm: FragmentManager? = fragmentManager
                val fragM: ChatListFragment =
                    fm?.findFragmentById(R.id.chatListFrag) as ChatListFragment
                fragM.clearAdapter()
            }
```

....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always a risk of finding a fragment in ViewPager, because the viewpager will not keep all the fragments (a little bit like RecyclerView). You can consider using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to send and receive `clear-data` events.

For more details, see It's easy to fix the NPT by changing `as` to `as?`. But your application may not behave as you expected (ChatAdapter will not be cleared)

Comment: I have already succeeded to access the second fragment with a simple modification.
By changing "findFragmentById(R.id.chatListFrag)" to "findFragmentById(ChatListFragment.id)"

view?.backSelBtn?.setOnClickListener {
                val fm: FragmentManager? = fragmentManager
                val fragM: ChatListFragment =
                    fm?.findFragmentById(ChatListFragment.id) as ChatListFragment
                fragM.clearAdapter()
            }

But, I still have a simple error, when moving between ViewPager2 fragments, it throwing a class cast exception.